# libcurl post request multiple lines

Tags: c, post, libcurl, mime

I am currently working on an application that needs to communicate between two web servers. In order to do that I am using libcurl in c. I am perfectly ok with making GET requests, but the POST ones I'm finding a bit more tricky.
For instance with curl in this case I'd do:

```
curl --location --request POST '%URL%' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--data-urlencode 'grant_type=client_credentials' \
--data-urlencode 'scope=%scope%' \
--data-urlencode 'client_id=%client_id%' \
--data-urlencode 'client_secret=%client_secret%'
```

Reading the libcurl documentation I understand I need to `curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1L);` to let libcurl know I'm posting.

The only problem I have is how exactly do I make the different lines?
The fact that the `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` is in fact called "fields" rather than "field" makes me think it should support multiple fields natively, so I instinctively think

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDSIZE, (long) strlen(first_line));
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, first_line);

curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDSIZE, (long) strlen(second_line));
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, second_line);

curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDSIZE, (long) strlen(third_line));
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, third_line);
```

...and so on.

But that doesn't work and the [documentation](https://curl.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS.html) goes on saying

> To make multipart/formdata posts, check out the CURLOPT_MIMEPOST option combined with curl_mime_init.

Which, since I know very little about, looks sort of scary especially looking at the example under [this page](https://curl.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_MIMEPOST.html).

Can anybody help me with the request I need to make or at least explain the MIME thing a little simpler?
From the mime page on curl.se I get the feeling that I should already know the things I don't know and the research I have done hasn't really shed any more light.

Comment: Run that `curl` command with the key `--libcurl file.c`, you will get a C code in the file.c you are looking for.

Comment: Nit: you do not want `--request POST` there, it might very well break your redirect following.

Answer (score 0):

Since the server is expecting the data in `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` format, MIME doesn't apply, so ignore that.

Despite its name, `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` is not treated in a plural manner. It cannot be used in multiple calls to `curl_easy_setopt()` to concatenate multiple pieces of data into a single `POST` body.  It expects the entire `POST` body to be specified in a single call, as per documented in [CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS explained](https://curl.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS.html):

> Pass a char * as parameter, **pointing to the full data to send in an HTTP POST operation. You must make sure that the data is formatted the way you want the server to receive it**. libcurl will not convert or encode it for you in any way. For example, the web server may assume that this data is URL encoded.

`curl.exe` concatenates multiple `--data...` parameters together into a single `POST` body:

> If any of these options is used more than once on the same command line, the data pieces specified will be merged with a separating &-symbol. Thus, using '-d name=daniel -d skill=lousy' would generate a post chunk that looks like 'name=daniel&skill=lousy'.

So, you will have to do the same in your own code, eg:

```c
// build up this string however you need to...
const char *post_body = "grant_type=client_credentials"
                        "&scope=<url-encoded value>"
                        "&client_id=<url-encoded value>"
                        "&client_secret=<url-encoded value>";

curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, post_body);

// no need for CURLOPT_POSTFIELDSIZE in this case,
// libcurl will handle that internally...
```